# lirc_zilog IR transmission no longer working with HD-PVR on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lirc, lirc-zilog

I have been running a ubuntu 10.04 with a patched version of lirc_zilog for two years. I upgraded to 12.04 and lirc_zilog is no longer working with my HD-PVR. The MythTV wiki reports that it did work out of the box with [11.04](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Hauppauge_HD-PVR#Steps_to_Enable_IR_Transmitter).

The error message I get on irsend is as follows:

```
johnf@carbon:~$ /usr/local/bin/irsend SEND_ONCE blaster 0_130_KEY_POWER
irsend: command failed: SEND_ONCE blaster 0_130_KEY_POWER
irsend: hardware does not support sending
```

The lircd daemon, run interactively, reports the following:

```
 lircd: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
 lircd: could not get hardware features
 lircd: this device driver does not support the LIRC ioctl interface
 lircd: major number of /dev/lirc0 is 250
 lircd: LIRC major number is 61
 lircd: check if /dev/lirc0 is a LIRC device
 lircd: WARNING: Failed to initialize hardware
 lircd: error processing command: SEND_ONCE blaster 0_130_KEY_POWER
 lircd: hardware does not support sending
 lircd: removed client
```

Checking dmesg seems to indicate that the kernel module is loading properly:

```
 [56497.730743] lirc_zilog: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
 [56497.730999] lirc_zilog: Zilog/Hauppauge IR driver initializing
 [56497.732484] lirc_zilog: ir_probe: ir_rx_z8f0811_hdpvr on i2c-0 (Hauppage HD PVR I2C), client addr=0x71
 [56497.732493] lirc_zilog: ir_probe: ir_tx_z8f0811_hdpvr on i2c-0 (Hauppage HD PVR I2C), client addr=0x70
 [56497.732496] lirc_zilog: probing IR Tx on Hauppage HD PVR I2C (i2c-0)
 [56497.756822] lirc_zilog: firmware of size 302355 loaded
 [56497.756945] lirc_zilog: 743 IR blaster codesets loaded
 [56497.757030] i2c i2c-0: lirc_dev: driver lirc_zilog registered at minor = 0
 [56497.757033] lirc_zilog: IR unit on Hauppage HD PVR I2C (i2c-0) registered as lirc0 and ready
 [56497.757035] lirc_zilog: probe of IR Tx on Hauppage HD PVR I2C (i2c-0) done
 [56497.757056] lirc_zilog: initialization complete
```

Here is my /etc/lirc/hardware.conf

```
 #Chosen IR Transmitter
 TRANSMITTER="HD-PVR"
 TRANSMITTER_MODULES="lirc_dev lirc_zilog"
 TRANSMITTER_DRIVER=""
 TRANSMITTER_DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
 TRANSMITTER_SOCKET=""
 TRANSMITTER_LIRCD_CONF=""
 TRANSMITTER_LIRCD_ARGS=""
```

My lircd.conf is a copy of the [recommended one](http://www.blushingpenguin.com/mark/lmilk/lircd.conf).

Examination of the kernel source seems to indicate that the lirc_zilog module should support transmission, it's newer than the patched version I was manually compiling on 10.04. I was previously using a manually built version of lirc 0.8.7 and not the packaged one. I'm now running the packaged version 9.0.

I can provide any additional information required and will perform tests quickly. I'm very eager to get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's odd...it works out of the box for me with 12.04.

Why are you using `/usr/local/bin/irsend` instead of the one in `/usr/bin/irsend`?

Here is an irsend command that works for me:

```
/usr/bin/irsend --device=/dev/lircd SEND_ONCE blaster 1_27_KEY_2
```

Perhaps you need to specify --device, and use the binary in /usr/bin?

Comment: You raise a very interesting point, I was previously using that path to reference the version I'd compiled manually. Strangely, after rebooting my system both irsend binaries are now working. I have no idea why/how this could happen with the large number of service restarts I performed and kernel module reloads but I am happy it works!